# Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.7 and Broadcom Wireless - no bcmwl

Tags: networking, 16.04, kernel, broadcom

I have manually installed Kernel 4.7 on *buntu 16.04. My WLAN (Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n) uses bcma and wl modules. Tried to add `broadcom-sta-dkms` via

```
apt install --reinstall
```

which detects Kernel 4.7 but reports:

```
Building initial module for 4.7.0-040700-generic ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic is not supported Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.7.0-040700-generic (x86_64)
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because kernel 4.7 is nout supported.

Comment: More generally we don't support custom kernels here. Please use a mainline kernel provided by Canonical or ask on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same situation. Here is what worked for me: Get the `.deb` package at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/amd64/broadcom-sta-dkms/6.30.223.271-3 and then

```
sudo dpkg -i broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-3_all.deb
```